# Process.WorkingSet64 returns max value of 4294967295

Tags: c#, memory, process, monitoring, system.diagnostics

I'm trying to monitor the memory of another process with C#. **However, the maximum memory value that Process.WorkingSet64 or Process.PrivateMemorySize64 will output is 4294967295.** I've also have the same problem with Performance Counters.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace perfmon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int pid;
            if (int.TryParse(args[0], out pid))
            {
                var p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);

                var ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", p.ProcessName);
                Console.WriteLine($"ProcessName:{p.ProcessName}");

                var ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
                p.Refresh();

                Console.WriteLine("WorkingSet64\tPrivateMemorySize64\tRam PC");
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.WorkingSet64}\t{p.PrivateMemorySize64}\t\t{ram}");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Running on Windows Server 2012 R2 with .net 4.61.

Output:

```
C:\XXX\perfmon>perfmon.exe 15800
ProcessName:XXX.Windows.Services
WorkingSet64    PrivateMemorySize64     Ram PC
4294967295      4294967295              4.294967E+09
```

Powershell output for process:

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> get-process -id 15800 | select-object -property workingSet64
WorkingSet64
------------
5079859200
```

Tasklist output for process:

```
C:\Users\xxx>tasklist /FI "PID eq 15800"

Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
XXX.Windows.Services         15800 Services                   0   5,031,424 K
```

As you can see, the C# process stops at 4294967295. However using powershell or tasklist continues to measure memory above 4 GB.

Is this a problem in my code or is this a known issue with memory measurement with C#/.net?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot reliably monitor a 64-bit process from a 32-bit app, numbers are cooked by the Wow64 emulator to prevent them from overflowing UInt32.MaxValue.  Just remove the jitter forcing so you can run as a 64-bit process as well.

Project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target = AnyCPU, untick Prefer 32-bit.

Comment: I actually just built it as x64 to be sure. This appears to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in your code and while I suspected some very improbable weird interaction between the c# 6.0 features and the 32bit vs 64bit properties, the NextValue() method on PerformanceCounter is a float, so no way.

That leads me to believe the problem is not .Net and not the code, but something in your system, like the WMI. Possible related: http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/13358955/Interesting+issue+with+ManagementEventWatcher+monitoring+registry+changes